# PyCharm disable switch opened files on branch switch

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

If I switch back to previously open branch PyCharm switch opened tabs.
But I have 5 different attached projects and this feature starts to bother.

Is there any way to disable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling **Restore workspace on branch switching** in **Settings | Version Control | Confirmation**. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-version-control-confirmation.html